# socket programming in C#

Tags: c#, client, server-side, tcpsocket

i'am trying to do Socket programming in C# and now i need to understand that do we need array of 
sockets in Server-side in order to handle multiple clients or one socket in server-side is sufficient for 
handling many clients;

And need to configure whether all data from server to client has been reached and the availability of server,discarding the client request .

Do we need to create multiple thread to handle each client also ? and i need to handle each client separetely.

Answer (score 6):

Each connection will require a new socket.  [As spender says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254700/socket-programming-in-c/5254722#5254722), you only listen with one socket, the socket API will create the other sockets when connection requests come in.

Read [the documentation for `accept`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737526.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

One listening socket can service many clients.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one socket to response multiple clients. When a client connet with the server, your application creates a socket to attend this conection.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [Writing scalable server applications using IOCP](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/iocp.aspx). This's a good tutorial on how to create a robust server application.

Answer (score 0):

you create one listener(welcome socket) which creates a dedicate connection socket for every accepted client.

I think you need some thing like.

```
private void listen(){

TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(5000);
listener.Start();
while (true)
{
  // Accept a new client
  Socket clientSocket = listener.AcceptSocket();
  //Create a thread for every client.
  ParameterizedThreadStart pThreadStart = new ParameterizedThreadStart(handleClient);
  Thread thread = new Thread(pThreadStart);
  thread.Start(clientSocket);
 }
}
```